# Update newsstand cover art without updating content

Tags: ios, iphone, newsstand-kit

I have added a new issue with a new cover art. But it is not appearing in the newsstand shelf. I don't want to update my app. How long will it take for the new cover art to appear on the newsstand shelf? Should I add a new version of the app to update the cover?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to update your application. You need to send a push notification with a very specific format.

The details can be found in the Newstand FAQ found

[How is the push notification that initiates the Newsstand background download different from other push notifications? Will I have to change or modify my backend infrastructure?](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2280/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011215-CH1-DELIVERING_YOUR_CONTENT-HOW_IS_THE_PUSH_NOTIFICATION_THAT_INITIATES_THE_NEWSSTAND_BACKGROUND_DOWNLOAD_DIFFERENT_FROM_OTHER_PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS___WILL_I_HAVE_TO_CHANGE_OR_MODIFY_MY_BACKEND_INFRASTRUCTURE_)

Comment: Im not sure about the notification. I just want to update the cover art image and I added an issue.

Answer (score 0):

It appeared today in the newsstand, it was just the matter of time. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

You can use some URL to get cover image. And when it is necessary to change cover, you can just change the image on that URL. For example:

```
    NSURL *getURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://youURL/main.png"];
    ASIHTTPRequest * getRequest = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:getURL];
    [getRequest startSynchronous];
    NSError *error = [getRequest error];
    if (!error) {
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"main.png"];
        NSData* responseString = [getRequest responseData];
        [responseString writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

        UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
        [app setNewsstandIconImage:result];
    }
```

Everytime you only need to change image on http: //youURL/main.png. That is all. 
I used here AsiHTTPRequest to download the image.

Answer (score 0):

It is clear from several sources including Apple’s own specification that the atom feed in newsstand is used for updating the App Icon and description found on the app store only and not used for updating the app icon in the newsstand folder on the device.

https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/NewsstandAtomFeedSpecification.pdf

"Newsstand is a feature of iOS 5 that allows your readers to access the latest issue of your newspaper or magazine. You host your content on your web server and provide the App Store with an Atom feed that provides updated metadata and cover art for each issue as it becomes available. The Newsstand Atom Feed XML (described in this document) is used to enable the **App Store** to display your app with the cover art and metadata that is relevant to the latest issue. 
This document specifies the Newsstand Atom Feed XML format for managing Newsstand issue metadata.
Newsstand issue metadata **is displayed on your Newsstand app’s product page in the App Store**. The metadata provided should accurately reflect the issues and content that are available within your app.
Newsstand issue metadata can be managed via the Newsstand Atom Feed or directly in iTunes Connect. The
Newsstand Atom Feed allows you to create new issues and update existing issues. The Newsstand Atom Feed
is processed daily. The Newsstand Atom Feed is based on the Atom 1.0 format."